# epsilon delta proof for $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{xy}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

I have to find some point in the domain of $f(x,y)$ such that limit goes to zero, where:
\begin{equation}
 f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{xy}
\end{equation}

For inspection, I found the point $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$. But I think that I have to prove the limit
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{xy}=0
\end{equation}
So for $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{xy}\right|<\varepsilon \hspace{0.5cm} \text{when} \hspace{0.5cm} 0<\sqrt{\left(x-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2}<\delta
\end{equation}
So this is
\begin{equation}
 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1-\sqrt{2}(x+y)}<\delta
\end{equation}
but I don't see the relation to prove this limit. Do you know some way to continue?

Comment: You should first identify the domain $D$ of $f$ and notice that on this domain, $f$ is continuous (because continuity is preserved by sum, product, quotient when defined). Then, the limit at a point of $D$ is equal to the value at this point and no proof is needed.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, the problem becomes much simpler when you focus on the continuity of the numerator and the denominator, and that at the pertinent point, the numerator is $(0)$ and the denominator is non-zero.  In my judgement however, the posting's title is making the legitimate request that such considerations be **ignored**, in favor of a back-to-basics $\epsilon,\delta$ demonstration.  See my answer.

Comment: Angie, what makes you "think that [you] have to prove the limit" and that you have no other tool at your disposal than the epsilon-delta *definition*? As you can see from the two answers below, it is quite heavy. Which *theorems* were you taught to avoid a systematic appeal to such techniques?

Comment: Dont't you remember of theorems about the limit of a sum, a product, a quotient?

Answer (score 0):

**My** standard approach to a problem like this is to **strive** to keep things $~\color{red}{\text{linear}}~$ between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  For this problem there are three artificial devices that facilitate this:

- Given two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ 
  let $D[(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)]$ denote the (non-negative) distance between the two points. 
  That is, 
  $D[(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)] = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}.$ 
   
  The first device is that 
  $0 < D[(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)] < \delta \implies $ 
  $0 \leq |x_1 - x_2| < \delta ~~\text{and}~~ 0 \leq |y_1 - y_2| < \delta.$
- For the second device, suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are all positive numbers. 
  Further suppose that you have two variables, that I shall call $u$ and $v$. 
  Further suppose that you know that 
  $A < u < B~~$ and $~~C < v < D.$ 
  Then you can **immediately conclude** that 
  $\displaystyle \frac{A}{D} < \frac{u}{v} < \frac{B}{C}.$ 
  The idea is that you **minimize** $~\dfrac{u}{v}~$ by **minimizing** its numerator and **maximizing** its denominator. 
  You **maximize** $~\dfrac{u}{v}~$ by the reverse process.
- Given $\epsilon > 0$, when you are constructing the relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, add an additional **maximum-value** constraint on $\delta$. 
  For example, in this problem, I will impose the constraint that $\delta$ must be $\leq \dfrac{1}{10}.$ 
  This implies that (for example) $\delta^2 \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10}.$ 
  This helps to keep things **linear**, between $\epsilon$ and $\delta.$

---

The challenge is to establish a relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ such that

$$0 < D\left[ ~(x,y),\left(~\sqrt{1/2},\sqrt{1/2}~\right) ~\right] < \delta \implies 
~\left|\frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{xy} - 0 ~\right| < \epsilon.$$

**Note**
There are much easier demonstrations of the posted assertion, that **in no way** involve $\epsilon,\delta$.  For example, it is clear that in the posted question, both the numerator and denominator are continuous functions, where the limit as $(x,y)$ approaches the pertinent point of the numerator is $(0)$ and the corresponding limit of the denominator is **not zero**.

Depending on what theory that you were taught, this makes it **game over**.  However, the OP (i.e. original poster) specifically mentioned that $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ should be used.  So, I will attack the problem from that viewpoint.

---

As discussed, since the distance between $(x,y)$ and $~\displaystyle \left(~\sqrt{1/2},\sqrt{1/2}~\right) ~$ is between $(0)$ and $(\delta),$ exclusive, you have that

- $\displaystyle 0 \leq |x - \sqrt{1/2}| < \delta < \frac{1}{10}.$
- $\displaystyle 0 \leq |y - \sqrt{1/2}| < \delta < \frac{1}{10}.$

This implies that $x,y$ are both bounded by:

- $\displaystyle \sqrt{1/2} - \delta < x < \sqrt{1/2} + \delta.$
- $\displaystyle \sqrt{1/2} - \delta < y < \sqrt{1/2} + \delta.$

This implies that

$$~\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta\sqrt{1/2} + \delta^2 < x^2 < \frac{1}{2} + 2\delta\sqrt{1/2} + \delta^2.$$

Since $\delta \leq \dfrac{1}{10}$, 
this implies that

$$~\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta\sqrt{1/2} < x^2 < \frac{1}{2} + \delta\left[2\sqrt{1/2} + \frac{1}{10}\right].$$

Further, since $~\displaystyle 2\sqrt{1/2} < 1.5~$ 
I can immediately conclude that

$$\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta < x^2 < \frac{1}{2} + 2\delta. \tag1 $$

By **parallel analysis** applied to the variable $(y)$, I can similarly conclude that

$$\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta < y^2 < \frac{1}{2} + 2\delta. \tag2 $$

This means that I know that the numerator, 
$(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ is bounded by

$$-4\delta < (x^2 + y^2 - 1) < 4\delta. \tag3 $$

---

Now, it is time to establish bounds on the denominator, $(xy)$.

Note that in the (small) neighborhood of radius $\delta$ around $~\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{1/2},\sqrt{1/2}\right),~$ that both of the coordinates of $(x,y)$ are positive.

Further, using (1) and (2) above, I have that

$$\left[\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta\right]^2 < (xy)^2 < \left[\frac{1}{2} + 2\delta\right]^2.$$

This implies [since $x,y$ are each known to be positive], that

$$\frac{1}{2} - 2\delta < (xy) < \frac{1}{2} + 2\delta. \tag4 $$

It only remains to

- put (3) and (4) above together
- use this to determine upper and lower bounds on the fraction, in terms of $\delta$
- use these bounds to construct the appropriate relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta.$

Since $0 < \delta \leq \dfrac{1}{10}$, I can immediately conclude that

$$0.3 \leq \frac{1}{2} - 2\delta < (xy) < \frac{1}{2} + 2\delta \leq 0.7. \tag5 $$

Since $\dfrac{1}{4} < 0.3$, I can therefore, immediately conclude that

$$\dfrac{1}{4} < (xy) < 1.$$

Now, I can use this in conjunction with (3) above.

I can now conclude that

$$\frac{-4\delta}{(1/4)} < \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{xy} < \frac{4\delta}{(1/4)} \implies $$

$$-16\delta < \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{xy} < 16\delta.$$

Therefore, I can conclude that the following relationship between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ will be satisfactory:

$$\delta = \min\left[ ~\frac{\epsilon}{16}, ~\frac{1}{10} ~\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

I always find it easier
to have variables in a limit
approach zero.
Accordingly,
in

$\begin{equation}
 \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}\frac{x^2+y^2-1}{xy}=0
\end{equation}$

I would let
$x=v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
y=w+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
$
and this becomes

$\begin{equation}
 \lim_{(v,w)\rightarrow \left(0, 0)\right)}\frac{(v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(w+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2-1}{(v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(w+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})}=0
\end{equation}$

Since

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{(v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2+(w+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})^2-1}{(v+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(w+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})}
&=\frac{(v^2+\sqrt{2}v+\frac12)+(w^2+\sqrt{2}v+\frac12)-1}{vw+(v+w)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac12}\\
&=\frac{v^2+w^2+\sqrt{2}(v+w)}{vw+(v+w)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac12}\\
\end{array}
$

as $(v, w) \to (0, 0)$,
the numerator goes to zero
and the denominator
is bounded away from zero
(this is not too hard to prove)
so the quotient
goes to zero.

Comment: The OP (i.e. original poster) is specifically asking for an $\epsilon,\delta$ demonstration.  I interpret this request to signify that the OP is not asserting that the $\epsilon,\delta$ approach is the simplest, or that such an approach builds on continuity theorems, which is normally the preferred method.

Comment: Based on my last expression, that is straightforward. I didn't want to explicitly solve it.